# OnListItemClick não funcionando em ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

O Toast do método onListItemClick nunca aparece, alguém sabe o que eu fiz de errado?
Codigo:

```
public class TiposFragment extends ListFragment  {
private ArrayList<Tipo> tipos;
private TipoAdapter tipoAdapter;
private int selecionado;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            tipos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("tipos");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (tipos != null) {
        try {
            tipoAdapter = new TipoAdapter(getContext(), tipos);
            setListAdapter(tipoAdapter);

            ListView listaTipos = getListView();
            listaTipos.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(listaTipos.getCount()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    selecionado = tipoAdapter.getItem(position).tipCod;
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(selecionado), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tipo_trilha, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer dessa forma ó:

```
public class TiposFragment extends ListFragment  {
    private ArrayList<Tipo> tipos;
    private TipoAdapter tipoAdapter;
    private int selecionado;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                tipos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("tipos");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", e.toString());
            // desnecessário mostrar o erro no app, use log para ver no console
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tipo_trilha,     container, false);
        // se voce passou o parametro corretamente para o bundle,
        // dificilmente irá precisar de um bloco try ... catch
        // se precisar, é só implementar ai de novo
        tipoAdapter = new TipoAdapter(getContext(), tipos);
        setListAdapter(tipoAdapter);

        ListView listaTipos = getListView();
        listaTipos.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listaTipos.setOnListItemClick(this);
        // muita atenção nessa linha, eu prefiro montar os meus proprios adapters.
        // por isso vc precisa verificar corretamente isso, mas o que deve estar faltando é isso
        // é através desse comando que o listview sabe onde 
        // procurar o listener do click, 
        // sem isso, ele nunca vai ser disparado
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        selecionado = tipoAdapter.getItem(position).tipCod;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(selecionado),    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

tenta assim, se der problemas, avisa ...

Comment: Não deu certo, mas eu nunca vi setar o listener para o onListItemClick

Comment: uma pergunta, voce precisa mesmo instanciar un ListFragment, ou pode ser outro tipo qualquer?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer tipo eu acho, mas tem que ser fragment

Comment: entaum cara, monta teu adapter e passa ele para um listview normal diretamente em um fragment, alem de ficar mais fácil de implementar, voce tem mais controle sobre os componentes. To corrido aqui agora, mas se voce esperar eu posto outra resposta com um exemplo, pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido! bastou adicionar a linha `android:focusable="false"` no xml do fragment